# How to programmatically remove Form controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a winForms application, where, each increase on the numericUpDown should, in the end, make the panel control visible, and create a textbox control, a picturebox, a numericUpDown control and three labels. And each decrease, should remove this group of controls. I've managed to write the code that creates the controls, but I have no idea how to remove them. My only guess, is to assign a name to every control, and then use the `colorPanel.Controls.RemoveByKey()`. Not quite sure what to do with `nameTextBoxPositionY` and `newLabelPositionY`, in their current state, they will probably screw everything up. Or should I just give up, and use a `switch(regionNumber)`, manually create the controls, and just make them visible depending on the numericUpDown value? Which would be quite a chore, considering that the max value for the numericUpDown is 10.

```
    private Label newLabel;
    private TextBox nameTextBox;
    private NumericUpDown heightNumericUpDown;
    private PictureBox colorPictureBox;
    private string[] newLabelText = {"Name", "Height", "Color"};

    private int newLabelPositionX = -3;
    private int newLabelPositionY = 5;

    private int nameTextBoxPositionX = 74;
    private int nameTextBoxPositionY = 2;
    private void numberOfRegions_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        int regionNumber = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRegions.Value);
        int numberOfLabels = 3;            

        if (regionNumber > 0)
        {
            colorPanel.Visible = true;                                                          
            for (int i = 0; i < regionNumber; i++)
            {
                nameTextBox = new TextBox();                                       
                nameTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(81, 20);
                nameTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(nameTextBoxPositionX, nameTextBoxPositionY);
                colorPanel.Controls.Add(nameTextBox);
                nameTextBoxPositionY += 78;                                                    
                for (int a = 0; a < numberOfLabels; a++)
                {
                    newLabel = new Label();
                    newLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(newLabelPositionX, newLabelPositionY);
                    newLabel.Text = newLabelText[a];
                    colorPanel.Controls.Add(newLabel);
                    newLabelPositionY += 26;                        
                }                                     
            }
            newLabelPositionY = 5;
            nameTextBoxPositionY = 2;               
        }
        else
        {
            colorPanel.Visible = false;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: All of the answers here have a very, *very* serious bug.  Controls that you remove from their parent's Controls collection **must** be disposed.  Failure to do so causes a permanent memory leak that the garbage collector does not fix.  Easy to diagnose with Task Manager btw, add the USER Objects column.  You'll see the displayed number for your process constantly increasing.  Your program crashes when it reaches 10,000.

Comment: So how one should go around to disposing said controls? I guess, it's not as easy, as calling `nameTextBox.Dispose()` in a `for` loop.

Comment: Just write a little struct that stores a reference to these 4 controls.  Use a `Stack<>` to store them.  Now it is simple.

Comment: you need to use a user control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I've fiddled with `Controls.RemoveByKey()` and found the solution:

```
struct DynamicFormControls
{
    public TextBox textBox;
    public Label label;
}

DynamicFormControls dynamicControls = new DynamicFormControls();
Stack<Control> controlStack = new Stack<Control>();
private string[] newLabelText = {"Name", "Height", "Color"};
private int newLabelPositionX = -3;
private int newLabelPositionY = 5;
private int nameTextBoxPositionX = 74;
private int nameTextBoxPositionY = 2;
private int numberOfLabels = 3;
private int currentValue = 0;
private int previousValue = 0;
private int difference = 0;
private int nameSuffix1 = 1;
private int nameSuffix2 = 1;

private void numberOfRegions_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentValue = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRegions.Value);
    if (currentValue == 0)
    {
        colorPanel.Visible = false;
        colorPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 10);
    }
    if (!ValueIncreased())
    {
        RemoveControls();
    }
    else
    {
        colorPanel.Visible = true;            
        CreateControls();
    }
}

private bool ValueIncreased()
{
    if (currentValue > previousValue)
    {
        difference = currentValue - previousValue;
        previousValue = currentValue;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        difference = previousValue - currentValue;
        previousValue = currentValue;
        return false;
    }
}

private void CreateControls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++)
    {
        dynamicControls.textBox = new TextBox();
        dynamicControls.textBox.Name = "textBox" + nameSuffix1;
        dynamicControls.textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(81, 20);
        dynamicControls.textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(nameTextBoxPositionX, nameTextBoxPositionY);                
        colorPanel.Controls.Add(dynamicControls.textBox);
        controlStack.Push(dynamicControls.textBox);
        nameTextBoxPositionY += 78;
        nameSuffix1++;                
        for (int a = 0; a < numberOfLabels; a++)
        {
            dynamicControls.label = new Label();
            dynamicControls.label.Name = "label" + nameSuffix2;
            dynamicControls.label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(newLabelPositionX, newLabelPositionY);
            dynamicControls.label.Text = newLabelText[a];
            colorPanel.Controls.Add(dynamicControls.label);
            controlStack.Push(dynamicControls.label);
            newLabelPositionY += 26;
            nameSuffix2++;
        }
    }
}

private void RemoveControls()
{
    for (int d = 0; d < difference; d++)
    {                
        for (int b = 0; b < 6; b++)
        {
            controlStack.Pop().Dispose();
        }
        nameSuffix1--;            
        if (nameTextBoxPositionY > 2)
        {
            nameTextBoxPositionY -= 78;
        }
        for (int t = 0; t < numberOfLabels; t++)
        {
            nameSuffix2--;
            if (newLabelPositionY > 5)
            {
                newLabelPositionY -= 26;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through your controls and remove unwanted items by name (assuming you store their names in array, or even tag assuming you assign a number tag to each created control (e.g. regionNumber)

```
foreach (Control item in colorPanel.Controls.OfType<Control>())
{
    foreach(var name in myItemNames) 
    {
        if (item.Name == name)
        {
            colorPanel.Controls.Remove(item);
            item.Dispose();
            //...
```

Or you could just clear the controls if that's what you actually want to achieve

```
colorPanel.Controls.Clear();
```

myItemNames here would be an array you assign to while generating the controls. e.g.

```
//before loop
myItemNames = new List<string>();

//...in loop
newLabel = new Label();
newLabel.name = "label"+i;
myItemNames.Add(newLabel.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Control.Controls.Remove` method:

```
this.Controls.Remove(Control);
```

Maybe change your code to use an array, then you can remove Controls by index:

```
TextBox[] MyTextBoxes = new TextBox[50];

foreach (TextBox textBox in MyTextBoxes)
    this.Controls.Add(textBox);

foreach (TextBox textBox in MyTextBoxes)
    this.Controls.Remove(textBox);
```